# Getting monthly average of maximum temperatures from ERA5 hourly netcdf data in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I would appreciate some help here.
I am struggling to get a time series of gridded and tabular data of the average maximum temperatures (1979-2019) for a specific region per month from a NetCDF file.
It is the first time I work with netcdf format, I have tried to convert it to .csv and then work with it as a dataframe but the dataset is too large (41 years of hourly data), and quite inefficient (I get problems trying to allocate vectors, when writing into the csv due to its size).

Is there any way to get the same outcome perhaps with the netcdf4 or raster packages?

Thank you very much!

This is the code to request the data from CDS Copernicus:

```
request <- list("dataset_short_name" = "reanalysis-era5-single-levels",
                "product_type" = "reanalysis",
                "variable" = "maximum_2m_temperature_since_previous_post_processing",
                "year" = c(""1979","1980","1981","1982","1983","1984","1985","1986","1987","1988","1989","1990","1991",
                           "1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005",
                           "2006", "2007","2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017","2018","2019"),
                "month" = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"),
                "day" = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"),
                "time" = c("00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"),
               
                "area" = "16/-6/9/3",
                "format" = "netcdf",
                "target" = "era5-wap-Tmax2m_1979_2019.nc")

file <- wf_request(user     = "ID",   # user ID (for authentification)
                   request  = request,  # the request
                   transfer = TRUE,     # download the file
                   path     = ".")      # store data in current working directory
```

Comment: It looks like you've got an extra `"` before `1979`. Also, to reduce typing, you can do things like: `year = as.character(1979:2019)` and `month=stringr::str_pad(1:12, width=2, pad="0")` and `time=paste0(stringr::str_pad(0:23, width=2, pad=0), ":00")`.

Comment: Also, can you add to your question the code to load the package(s) you're using?

Comment: [This tutorial](https://pjbartlein.github.io/REarthSysSci/netCDF.html) on using NetCDF files in R might be helpful. Also, you could write a loop to write one year of data at a time, which might overcome the memory issues. There may be better options (I'm not familiar with the NetCDF format or the ECMWF website), but saving a separate file for each year might be a quick workaround.

Comment: Thanks! it finally worked, dividing it into smaller chunks and combining it later.